# problem of arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic

You can only use the numbers $1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15$.

You can also repeat the numbers.

Fill in the blanks: ____ $+$ ____ $+$ ____ $=30$

Comment: Sum of $3$ odd numbers can't be equal to even number.

Comment: Whats the context? What makes you think this is possible? As pointed out buy @Oleg567 the sum of 3 odd numbers will be odd.

Comment: @WarrenHill The context of this question: it's a thing people copy and paste on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be 13.7 + 15.3 + 1 = 30

Comment: Absolutely no way this is true.

Comment: This doesn't *really* answer the question, but its kinda funny. This would be better as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by previous answer,

$$
3! + 11 + 13 = 30.
$$